# Elasticsearch count number of occurrences

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to write a elastic search query that will show me the number of returning users to a site. The following query return all unique users for a day by site. I am looking for the number of users that landed on a site only once for the time period.

```
 GET 2015.*/_search?search_type=count
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": "now-1d/d",
                  "lte": "now-1d/d"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "fquery": {
                "query": {
                  "query_string": {
                    "query": "event:script_initiated"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "fquery": {
                "query": {
                  "query_string": {
                    "query": "session_depth:0"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "Site Name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "site_name",
        "size": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "uniques": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "user_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to not do a search for every user_id and do counts outside of ES.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [metric aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) and write a script for this.
In the script , you can check if the same user name has come across multiple documents and hence see the number of occurrence of a user.

Or you can wait to get the issue refereed in this [bug](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/9124) resolved.